# ssis filter out rows with values starting in a letter

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

In an SSIS project I am trying to filter out rows from an Excel file source where a column has values that start in a letter and followed by numbers. Some cells contain more that one value and not all cells follow a data type format. The data flow is currently as follows:
`Excel Source > Data Conversion > OLE DB Destination`
I am adding a Conditional Split after the Excel Source, but I am troubled with how to filter out unneeded records. Below are examples of values that should not be included before the end of the data flow:

```
Row      Value
1        1234
2        P123
3        P1234, P456
4        rec P678
```

Row 1 should be the only one that should flow to the destination. Is there a way to filter out records that start with 'P' and followed by numbers, regardless of how many values in each cell?
Update: I'm currently working around FINDSTRING(Value,"P",1) > 0 || FINDSTRING(Value,"p",1) > 0. The output blocks rows 2-4 but the Value for row 1 was changed to 0. Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: just follow the example and implement in your requirement https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-conditional-split/

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response but I am looking for a more specific coding advice for my Conditional Split. Basically the Split should "block out" the other rows since they contain records with P's as their first character, but is followed by numbers. This means that if a value is "Person Value 1234", this record should not be blocked since The "P" is not followed by numerals. My current code (that doesn't work yet) is:

FINDSTRING(Value,"P",1) > 0 && CODEPOINT(SUBSTRING([Value],FINDSTRING(Value,"P",1),3)) > 47 && CODEPOINT(SUBSTRING(Value,FINDSTRING(Value,"P",1),7)) < 58

Comment: I'm guessing the your first row changes to zero might have something to do with the Excel driver's *terrible* approach to guessing data types. It's guessed the data type wrong and there's not much you can do about it. At this likn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141683.aspx read the section entitled _Missing Values_. This issue is all over the internet. I don't know why your values are zero instead of NULL but I'm pretty sure that's it. Look up *IMEX* for a workaround

Comment: Zero is the expected return from FINDSTRING() when it doesn't find something.  FINDSTRING() counts occurrences of a string.  Integer is its return.  When it doesn't find something, zero occurrences is expected.

Answer (score 2):

### 1st Solution: Script Component with a .Net method to check whether a value is a number.

1. Script Component

   Add a Script Component (type: transformation) where you need to do the check.
2. Select Input Columns

   Add the column that needs to be checked as  input column.
3. Add Output Column

   Add a new column to the Output columns on the tab Inputs and Outputs. The type shoot be Boolean and give it a suitable name.
4. The Script

```
' VB.Net code
' Check whether the string value contains a number
    Imports System
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Math
    Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
    Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper

 
    Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent

    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
        ' Standard VB.net method, indicating whether
        ' an expression can be evaluated as a number
        If (IsNumeric(Row.InputCol)) Then
            Row.IsNumeric = True
        Else
            Row.IsNumeric = False
        End If
    End Sub

    End Class
```

5. Create a conditional split to filter Rows

### 2nd Solution: Derived Column

1. Add Derived Column

   Add a Derived Column where you need to do the check.
2. Add Expression

   Add a new column with the following expression and give it a suitable name: `!ISNULL((DT_I8)TextNumbers)`. All numbers will result in True and all non-numbers will raise an error.
3. Ignore error

   Go to the Configure Error Output window in the Derived column and ignore errors for the new field.
4. The Result

   Add a conditional split to filter rows using `ISNULL` expression

### 3rd Solution: Data Conversion

1. Data Conversion

   An alternative to the second solution could be to try convert the value to an int via a Data Conversion Transformation and also ignore any errors. Than add a conditional split to filter rows using `ISNULL` expression

Answer (score 0):

The condition you want to check looks whether a field is numeric or not. Unfortunately we do not have straightforward ISNUMERIC funtion within SSIS.

Please go thru the following link. We can achieve this with the use of derived columns.

[Check IsNumeric() with Derived Column Transform in SSIS Package](http://bidn.com/blogs/DustinRyan/ssis/915/check-isnumeric-with-derived-column-transform-in-ssis-package)