# Validating Records before imported into Database in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, validation, ssis, ssis-2012

I am using SSIS

I am importing Data from Excel file into SQL Server table.

There are certain records that are in Excel that should not be imported 
i.e. Sales < 100

How can I add this validation between my Source which is Excel source and my destination which is OLE DB destination.
from what I found on google there can be a control between 
Excel source and my destination which is OLE DB destination that can make the validation and ignore the un-needed records.

Comment: Read into a temp table using `BULK INSERT` and then insert into your actual target table using a where clause.

Comment: This is not my question.. my question is for SSIS not SQL scripting!

Comment: I can't reopen it for some reason, but I have voted to reopen.  You should have told us SSIS from the start.

Comment: The question title says SSIS from the beginning !

Comment: try open it again, you should be able to now

Comment: I already voted, I can't vote again :-(

Comment: you can open it yourself, without voting

Comment: You can add *Conditional Split* transformation after *Source*, and direct rows which satisfy given condition to a specific output. Then direct this output to your destination.

Comment: Maybe this is a better duplicate:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714258/ssis-filter-out-rows-with-values-starting-in-a-letter